# Why is the sidebar not falling to the bottom? (Bootstrap 3.1)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am mocking out a site in bootstrap 3.1, and I think I am doing something wrong. The following html, I am under the impression that `col-xs-2` (with: some content) should fall to the bottom of the screen under `col-xs-8`, How ever the actual case is that `col-xs-2` shrinks as much as possible and then `col-xs-8` sits on top of it.`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2"> some content </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8"> Main Content </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-md-8`+`col-md-2` or `col-lg-8`+`col-lg-2` for the desired effect.

Actually `col-xs-#` is a class which maintains the layout in smaller screens too. For the grid layout to work as desired, `col-lg-#` or `col-md-#` is used.

Here's the table from the website of Bootstrap that depicts the grid systems:

[image: Grid Options]

Read more about the grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Comment: So i can't use xs? Why is that - out of curiosity

Comment: Earlier (in bootstrap 2.3.2 and lower), instead of `col-xx-#` there used to be just a `span` that did what you want to achieve. But later on they incorporated different kinds of layouts. Now say you want the layout to look the same as in your desktop in your Mobile device. What do you do? Use `xs`! That's it!